# Recursive webclient.download method with 404 responses is causing server to reach 100%

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to download files through webclient and the code is like the one given below. The problem is that if I get continuous 404 response alot of times, my server reaches to 100% and viewing the event log tells that stack overflow happened. Here the "count" variable is to avoid 0 byte files and count404 is for 404 responses.

```
    int count = 0; int count404 = 0;
    public Stream DownloadFileThroughWebClient(string strFilePath)
    {
        try
        {
            if (count >= 120 || count404 >= 30)
            {
                count = 0;
                count404 = 0;
                return null;
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
            var v = wc.DownloadData(strFilePath);
            Stream FileToSave = new MemoryStream(v);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[FileToSave.Length];
            int numBytesToRead = (int)FileToSave.Length;
            if (numBytesToRead > 0)
            {
                count = 0;
                count404 = 0;
                return FileToSave;
            }
            else
            {
                count++;
                count404 = 0;
                return DownloadFileThroughWebClient(strFilePath);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            count++;
            count404++;
            return DownloadFileThroughWebClient(strFilePath);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should wrap your WebClient in a `using` block.

Comment: Hey @codesparkle thanks for ur response.. I think its because of recursive exceptions, my server is getting high on CPU?  You have given me new point to think.

Comment: not disposing the WebClient isn't likely to cause a stack overflow as you are experiencing (that's more likely from recursion). It's a good idea to do it anyway though. To avoid a stack overflow, you may need to implement an *explicit* stack. Google "replace recursion with iteration".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (without using recursion and counts the 404s correctly):

```
public Stream DownloadFileThroughWebClient(string strFilePath)
{
    int count = 0; 
    int count404 = 0;

    while (count < 120 && count404 < 30)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] v;
            using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                v = wc.DownloadData(strFilePath);
            }

            if (v.Length > 0)
            {
                return new MemoryStream(v);
            }

            count++;
            count404 = 0;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            count++;
            var httpWebResponse = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            if (httpWebResponse != null && httpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                count404++;
                // you may wanna break out of the loop here since there's no point in continuing 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You call:

```
return DownloadFileThroughWebClient(strFilePath);
```

If something goes wrong. If it keeps getting a 404 (or more likely: ip-blocked for abuseive querying), then **of course** you will stackoverflow. That is what *happens* if you call yourself recursively too many times. So: don't do that. Some kind of "while" loop (with a sanity exit condition for either success or persistent failure) seems more appropriate than recursion.